# How can I escape the *s and %s in this string without breaking the URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, parsing, escaping

I have this action here:

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {
NSString *textString = self.symbolSearchField.text;
NSURL *sourceURL = [[NSURL alloc]  initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%%20*%%20from%%20yahoo.finance.quotes%%20where%%20symbol%%20in%%20%%28%%22%@%%22%%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys", textString]];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sourceURL];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
```

I want it to take the text from the search field, modify the URL with that text, and parse the XML from the URL. However, when I escape the *s and %s, it appears the URL becomes "broken", and it doesn't parse. If I leave the URL as it was without escaping...

```
    NSURL *sourceURL = [[NSURL alloc]  initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22%@%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys", textString]];
```

... then I get an "Invalid conversion specifier '*'" and a "More '%' conversions than data arguments" warning.

So my question is, how can I escape the symbols without breaking the URL?

**Edit**

For clarity, here is the code I have at the moment after making some adjustments.

`NSString *textString = self.symbolSearchField.text;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in (\"%@\")", textString];
    NSString *escapedStoreURL = [@"store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *escapedQuery = [query stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%@&env=%@", escapedQuery, escapedStoreURL];
    NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sourceURL];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *firstPart = @"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22";
NSString *lastPart = @"%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
NSURL *sourceURL = [[NSURL alloc]  initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", firstPart, textString, lastPart]];
```

## Edit

You may also want to consider escaping that query programmatically instead of having all that escaping in there beforehand. The store URL also needs to be URL encoded.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in (\"%@\")", textString];
NSString *escapedStoreUrl = [@"store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSString *escapedQuery = [query stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%@&env=%@", escapedQuery, escapedStoreUrl];
```

## <del>Edit 2</del>

<del>So I got back and was looking at this problem again, and it turns out there were some invisible characters between the u and the o in `yahoo.finance.quotes` and the two Ls of `alltableswithkeys` (Specifically, two of [U+200c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner)). Removing these should fix your issue.</del>  Turns out this was [caused by StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert).

Comment: Still does not parse. Used NSLog to see if the URL was still broken and this is the output: `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select220from2ahoo.finance.quotes2here          Ãô¯7ö¯7+Éymbol                   0n22SLA2&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys`

Comment: Okay, two things: First, it looks like you just did NSLog(string) instead of NSLog(@"%@", string), which is why the percent signs disappeared. Second, What the string you're trying substitute in there?

Comment: Right, silly me. The output is now `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys`, and that works, but it still does not parse. The string I want to substitute is a stock symbol (e.g. AAPL).

Comment: @user3874680 Perhaps the store URL needs to be encoded as well? I've updated my answer with an example of that.

Comment: Both of your suggested methods seem to produce valid URLs, and the string to URL conversion is all good, but it still is not parsing the XML. That makes no sense because when I NSLog sourceURL, it logs it, but when I try to parse sourceURL it does nothing.

Comment: It won't even parse `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.qu‌​otes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys`? If that one isn't working, I'm stumped. You could try throwing in another `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` around the `NSURL initWithString:` call, but that's kind of a band-aid and it'd be better to find the source of the problem...

Comment: @user3874680 See my most recent edit. Somehow you had gotten some non-printing characters in there that were messing things up.

Comment: There appears to be some sort of problem with the search field only, as when I used the exact same code and set the textString to "AAPL" and parsed it regularly, it worked. But when I try to make the string have the content of the text field, it doesn't parse.

Comment: Well, that brings us to the obvious question: what's the value of the text field?

Comment: The first view controller that appears after launch has a text field. The user enters a stock ticker, like AAPL, into the text field, presses the search button, which should activate the action which takes the string, modifies the URL, and parses it. There are some labels that should have the parsed data present in them.

Comment: Right. But set a breakpoint or NSLog that value. Look at what's *actually* there. I'd hazard a guess it's something more than "AAPL", or it would be working. You probably need to sanitize it somehow.

Comment: I have already used NSLog, it is outputting exactly what I put in, so at this point really nothing should be going wrong, but obviously there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Does `textString.length == 4`? If not, your string isn't *actually* "AAPL".

Comment: NSLog of the string length returns 4, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a NSMutableString, and append the strings step-by-step?

```
NSString *textString = @"AAPL";
NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSString *startString = @"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22";
NSString *endString = @"%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";

[query appendString:startString];
[query appendFormat:@"%@",textString];
[query appendString:endString];

NSURL *sourceURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:query];
```

Now, the variable `sourceURL` is your URL with the symbols "escaped".

Comment: @user3874680 It may be because the variable `query` is a NSMutableString- I've updated the answer with an NSURL.